# Hide tabs bar in terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/6huq0m/can_i_hide_the_terminals_tab_bar_when_only_a/) doesn't work for me (`org.pantheon...` not found) on Juno. Is there any workaround?

Is it moved somewhere? I'm using tmux so I don't mind even permanently hide that tab.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

These are the commands you're looking for:

- `gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings tab-bar-behavior 'Always Show Tabs'`
- `gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings tab-bar-behavior 'Hide When Single Tab'`
- `gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings tab-bar-behavior 'Never Show Tabs'`

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can do it atm.
New features are expected, like blur, but a lot has changed since the previous version, that's why `org.pantheon.terminal.settings` isn't found.
For some aspects, Elementary Juno final, still feels like a beta.